# Can C++ allocate page-locked memory?

Tags: c++, gsl

Basically, I have a gsl matrix which needs to be allocated into the page-locked memory. gsl_matrix_alloc doesn't specify this. It seems I have to redirect the pointers in my gsl_matrix->data. However, is there any C++ method that can allocate page-locked memory?

Note: I can't use other non-standard C++ API such as CUDA API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux, look at the manual for `mlock`.

```
> NAME
>        mlock, munlock, mlockall, munlockall - lock and unlock memory
> 
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <sys/mman.h>
> 
>        int mlock(const void *addr, size_t len);
>        int munlock(const void *addr, size_t len);
> 
>        int mlockall(int flags);
>        int munlockall(void);
```

Answer (score 4):

If by page-locked you mean virtual memory that is locked in physical memory, Windows has VirtualLock() and Linux has memlock().